# How do I send comment to the planner Task that has been just created. Conversation Thread comes to null for them

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-planner

[image]I know conversations are on the group level, but https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/******-****-4f19-be0e-********/conversations does not give any conversation id of newly created Planner Tasks. 
I need to send some comments while I create a task or maybe right after it, but with conversation thread coming null I have no option other than manually commenting on the platform. When I create a new task through a service I do get one comment by default stating "New Task has been created" but apparently that comment has no conversation id. Attached is an image of the default comment given to us without any conversation Id. Like I said if I have conversationsid then I can easily post a comment to that id or reply to it.

I am trying to send a comment when I create tasks like other fields such as startedDateTime and descriptions but somehow comment can not be posted from the beginning.

Comment: Could you please share the image? Are you trying to [Reply to a message in channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messagereply?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)? To do so you will need a messageID which you could get from [List Channel Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). Please let me know if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Thank you for your response. I am trying to send the comment to the planner Task, not channel. I am trying to figure out how to send the first comment on the task with conversationId. Because the image above has a comment by default but conversationId comes null.

Answer (score 1):

I could not mark your response as an answer but thank you so much it worked the way you said. Basically I created a thread in the group level and Update specific task with that conversation thread Id and now the comment I made to the thread is posted on the task.

Answer (score 0):

Conversations are not automatically created when the task is created. It is only created when someone created an actual comment. The Planner Web experience shows the creation automatically, without an actual conversation backing it up. You can create a thread in the group then update the task with its id, then it should uniformly show up everywhere.

Comment: What amazes me is that it requires the `Group.ReadWrite.All` permission, and which admin would give that?? Surely not ours. Our Planner interface in R works great, but we cannot initiate comments (but can continue in an existing thread). Insane.